# Remove focus from textbox when it is only editable control

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a textbox (textBox1) that I need to not have focus when the user hits a current page. The problem is that I cannot focus on another controller, [because the textbox is the only control that allows input.](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/347312/textbox-disable-focus)

I have a few hidden fields but focusing on them does not remove focus from the textbox (`hidden1.Focus()`).

I saw somewhere that you can disable and enable the controller, but that did not work either.

Ideas?

**EDIT**

Here are the controls I have:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblHide" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden1" runat="server" value="false"/>

 //C# code
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {      
     TextBox1.TabIndex = -1;
     lblHide.Focus();
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean, "controller"? Do you mean, "Control"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the text box to:

```
tabindex = -1
```

or

```
tabstop = false
```

The above depends on the type of control you are using, whether it is a asp control or html control.
Then add a label like:

```
<label id="lblHide" name="lblHide" hidden="hidden">
```

then set focus to that label.

***UPDATE***

So, here's what it will look like for you:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TabIndex="-1" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

and then on page load this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Label1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: I added an edit. Apparently the webcontrol does not have a tabstop property. I added edits in my question to show the code.

Comment: Update to reflect how it should look.  The downfall to this is that if the user clicks the box, focus will return to the textbox.

Comment: One option you do have, is to replace the textbox with a label.  This would eliminate the focus all together.  just have anything that is populated in the textbox, populate in the label instead.  Plus, you could make it look just like a textbox.  such as `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" text="test" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px"></asp:Label>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but I'll just follow what you already have... First make sure that your `TextBox` control has its `TabStop` property set to `False`. Then about your hidden controls, you might want to place this code under your main `Textbox` control's `GotFocus()` event...

```
hidden1.SelectText();
```

Comment: I tried to add `hidden1.Select()` to my hidden field, and I got an error saying no such method exists. I added the controls I used in my question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I thought this was on WinForms. I just noticed the tag WebForms. Did you just add this? Anyways... I edited the code, try it :)